# Getting JSON Array elements as records

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to extract elements from a simple JSON array in a PostgreSQL table like:

```
id(int)  vtags(jsonb)
-------- -----------------------
1        {"tags": ["a","b","c"]}
2        {"tags": ["x","y"]}
```

I would like to devise a `SELECT` statement to produce an output like:

```
id  tags
--- -----------------------
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   x 
2   y
```

Comment: Have you checked out the Postgres JSON docs? They're pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to unnest the elements of the array:

```
select t.id, 
       jt.tag
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(jt.vtags -> 'tags') as jt(tag)
order by t.id;
```